# Metro Attach FadeInAnimation to an Image

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

I've got the following that should work:

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard1">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image1" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard2">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image2" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard3">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image3" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard4">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image4" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard5">
        <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Image5" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Image Source="../Assets/image.png" x:Name="Image1" />
<Image Source="../Assets/image.png" x:Name="Image2" />
<Image Source="../Assets/image.png" x:Name="Image3" />
<Image Source="../Assets/image.png" x:Name="Image4" />
<Image Source="../Assets/image.png" x:Name="Image5" />
```

C#

```
//fades in the plane image 
private void FadeIn(int Index)
{
    if (Index == 0)
        FadeInStoryboard1.Begin();
    else if (Index == 1)
        FadeInStoryboard2.Begin();
    else if (Index == 2)
        FadeInStoryboard3.Begin();
    else if (Index == 3)
        FadeInStoryboard4.Begin();
    else
        FadeInStoryboard5.Begin();
}
```

The above code works - but there's got to be a better way.  Is there a way to either (A) put the Storyboard objects into a list that I can access by index, or (B) attach the Storyboard object to the Image object that is its target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is iterating through resources and checking their name an option?

```
string name = "FadeInStoryboard" + index;
foreach (object resource in this.Resources)
{
    if (resource is System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard storyboard = (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)resource;
        if (storyboard.Name == name) storyboard.Begin();

    }
  }
```

If you had a pattern in Keys, then you probably could use

```
this.Resources.FindByName("MyKey"+index)
```